# Separar una url con Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Quisiera poder guardar la url en una variable, la url viene de esta manera

https://www.midominio.com/sites/document/indice1.txt
solo necesito /sites/document/indice1.txt

gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza la clase [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL), esta tiene varias propiedades que te permiten extraer fácilmente las partes de la url.

```js
var url = new URL('https://www.midominio.com/sites/document/indice1.txt');
var path = url.pathname;
console.log(path);
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = "https://www.midominio.com/sites/document/indice1.txt";
  var a = str.indexOf("/sites");

  var text = str.substring(a, str.length);

  console.log(text);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente esta de igual manera, muchas gracias!